# Are there any free/open-source WCF client frameworks/libraries out there?

Tags: .net, python, automated-tests, wcf-client

I am working on a tool that will test the server of a Silverlight application. AFAIK, Silverlight uses [WCF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation) to communicate with the server. I am curious if here are any free tools out there that can enable to write test scripts that test the server via WCF, preferably in Java, Python, Ruby or anything that does not require .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WCFStorm](http://www.wcfstorm.com/wcf/home.aspx), haven't used it yet myself but it seems ok. Of course, it's a tool not a library, and it uses .Net (as it's the most logical choice for a tool that interoperates with WCF).

Comment: Thank you. Too bad it isn't free (only a 15 day trial) :(. I would have liked using IronPython.

Comment: I think there's a free lightweight version... maybe it's enough for your needs? Edit: actually I took a glance at the feature comparison and it says it cannot save and load projects or run from command line, so I question the usefulness.